# Sending emails on multiple dates for recipients of every month in an year

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I need to create a SharePoint email workflow using SharePoint designer 2013 which need to send emails to the recipients on particular date in every month of an year.Dates are different for every month(Eg: Jan-3rd,Feb-7th,March-11th....)...can you please help me by solving this.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint Designer 2013 (or 2010), you can create a workflow that pauses until a specific date and then resumes to send your alert. To send the first email of the year you can once manually start the workflow and the workflow kicks off and continue. Then it pauses until the date you want, sends the email, and then pauses again until the next date.

To the best of my knowledge this is all you can do with a SharePoint Designer workflow.

Just to share an example with you...

[image]

Add all your email recipients in a SharePoint group (below Home Visitors is my SharePoint group). For sending email on a specific date of month in a year you will end up writing 11 'then Pause until...' action in the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Create a custom list that holds the specific dates
2. Create a SPD 2013 workflow that triggers as you see fit. The workflow :

[image]

I have employee list as the source of data here. I am sending an email everytime the  `'created' = today`

[image]

This is just an example around how you can implement a logic in SPD around the problem statement.